# How to clear array in Firebase Cloud database?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I have a an array of tokens in my Cloud database. I want to clear it (keep an empty database). I tried:

```
connectedGroup.collection("cars").document(carName).update("tokens", FieldValue.arrayUnion());
```

Does it really cleans the array? It feels strange because I thought `arrayUnion` is expecting an object. What is the proper way to clear array's content in the database? I also thought to use:

```
connectedGroup.collection("cars").document(carName).update("tokens", new ArrayList<>());
```

Which is better?

Answer (score 1):

`FieldValue.arrayUnion()` is used when you want to *add new elements* to an array field, as described in its [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#arrayUnion(java.lang.Object...)).  If you want to make sure an array field is empty, then just write an empty array to it as you are in the second example.